# Unusual column vector notation with only a left bar to wrap components

Tags: notation, vectors

I know there are two standard forms to specify an n-dimensional column vector $\mathbf{\vec{v}}$ using square brackets or parentheses:
$$\mathbf{\vec{v}} = \begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \\ \vdots \\ v_{n - 1} \\ v_n \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \\ \vdots \\ v_{n - 1} \\ v_n \end{pmatrix}$$
But I have seen someone working in maths writing a form of column vector using only a left vertical bar instead of brackets, like so:
$$\mathbf{\vec{v}} = \left\lvert
 \begin{matrix}
  v_1 \\ v_2 \\ \vdots \\ v_{n - 1} \\ v_n
 \end{matrix}
 \right.$$
I tried to search on Internet about this form with no dice. So I wonder what it is called, or if it's actually an incorrect notation.

Comment: There is no difference in meaning between using square braces or parentheses to enclose a matrix. They are just notational conventions that people choose between. They are not "two standard forms", but "two common conventions". There is no particular reason an author cannot use a different notation if they feel like it. Because it is not a common notation, the author needs to introduce the notation instead of relying on others to just recognize it, but it they feel it is useful, there is no reason for them not to take this extra step and use whatever notation they like.

Comment: A notation with such a vertical bar is commonly used to denote an algorithm rather than a vector.